OneToMany Relation errors with org.hibnernate.MappingException Unable to find column with logical name
I than for all support. I read several answers here and on hibernate project, but still get this Exception:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: userentity_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(userentity) and its related supertables and secondary tables at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:839) at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:126) at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:104) at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1750) at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1694) at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ... 42 more
UserEntity has the list of AddressEntity
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import edu.remad.tutoring2.appconstants.RegexAppConstants;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Builder.Default;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "userentity")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.USERNAME_REGEX)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.EMAIL_REGEX)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    private Boolean enabled;

    @Default
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_rules", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<TokenEntity> tokens;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.FIRST_NAME_REGEX)
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.LAST_NAME_REGEX)
    private String lastName;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.GENDER_REGEX)
    private String gender;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.CELL_PHONE_REGEX)
    private String cellPhone;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userentity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
    
    @Column(name = "creation_date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
}

AddressEntity is an entry:
package edu.remad.tutoring2.models;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class AddressEntity {

    /**
     * the primary key for an address
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    /**
     * the street
     */
    private String addressStreet;

    /**
     * house number
     */
    private String addressHouseNo;

    /**
     * customer's zip code
     */
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "zipcode_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param addressStreet  address's street
     * @param addressHouseNo address's house number
     * @param addressZipCode address's zipcode
     */
    public AddressEntity(String addressStreet, String addressHouseNo, ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode) {
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
        this.addressHouseNo = addressHouseNo;
        this.addressZipCode = addressZipCode;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param id             address's id
     * @param addressStreet  address's street
     * @param addressHouseNo address's house number
     * @param addressZipCode address's zipcode
     */
    public AddressEntity(Long id, String addressStreet, String addressHouseNo, ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
        this.addressHouseNo = addressHouseNo;
        this.addressZipCode = addressZipCode;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public AddressEntity() {
    }

    /**
     * Gets Id
     *
     * @return Adress's Id
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets street
     *
     * @return adress's street
     */
    public String getAddressStreet() {
        return addressStreet;
    }

    /**
     * Sets street
     *
     * @param addressStreet address's street to set
     */
    public void setAddressStreet(String addressStreet) {
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
    }

    /**
     * Gets house number
     *
     * @return address's house number
     */
    public String getAddressHouseNo() {
        return addressHouseNo;
    }

    /**
     * Sets house number
     *
     * @param addressHouseNo address's house number
     */
    public void setAddressHouseNo(String addressHouseNo) {
        this.addressHouseNo = addressHouseNo;
    }

    public ZipCodeEntity getAddressZipCode() {
        return addressZipCode;
    }

    public void setAddressZipCode(ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode) {
        this.addressZipCode = addressZipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(addressHouseNo, addressStreet, addressZipCode, id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AddressEntity other = (AddressEntity) obj;
        return Objects.equals(addressHouseNo, other.addressHouseNo)
                && Objects.equals(addressStreet, other.addressStreet)
                && Objects.equals(addressZipCode, other.addressZipCode) && id == other.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddressEntity [id=" + id + ", addressStreet=" + addressStreet + ", addressHouseNo=" + addressHouseNo
                + ", addressZipCode=" + addressZipCode + "]";
    }
}


I tried several answer from stackoverflow and used hivernbate documnetation, but I was not able to solve exception.
This worked on another server, but now on new development server I get this exception.

can you add the table structures of userentity and Address?

Basically, you are trying to setup a uni-directional oneToMany relationship.
Here, your joinColumn in this case should refer AddressEntity id.
@Entity
@Table(name = "userentity")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userentity_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressentity_id", referencedColumnName = "userentity_id")
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class AddressEntity {

    /**
     * the primary key for an address
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="addressentity_id")
    private long id;
}

You can also refer the article for understanding the hibernate mappings: Uni-directional mapping

Thank you. I got this really wrong.

Many thanks again. Your mentioned solution worked like a charme.
I got also the bi-directional OneToMany mapping working. Here is the solution:
"One" is "UserEntity" and "Many" is "AddressEntity".
I add annontation OneToMany on member addresses (List).
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import edu.remad.tutoring2.appconstants.RegexAppConstants;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Builder.Default;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "userentity")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.USERNAME_REGEX)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.EMAIL_REGEX)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    private Boolean enabled;

    @Default
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_rules", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<TokenEntity> tokens;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.FIRST_NAME_REGEX)
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.LAST_NAME_REGEX)
    private String lastName;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.GENDER_REGEX)
    private String gender;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexAppConstants.CELL_PHONE_REGEX)
    private String cellPhone;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
    
    @Column(name = "creation_date", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
}

I added ManyToOne annotatitio to "user". You do not need annotation joincolumn, nevertheless I did that. Use name of variable / member user.
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class AddressEntity {

    /**
     * the primary key for an address
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name="address_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    /**
     * the street
     */
    private String addressStreet;

    /**
     * house number
     */
    private String addressHouseNo;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    private UserEntity user;

    /**
     * customer's zip code
     */
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "zipcode_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param addressStreet  address's street
     * @param addressHouseNo address's house number
     * @param addressZipCode address's zipcode
     */
    public AddressEntity(String addressStreet, String addressHouseNo, ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode) {
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
        this.addressHouseNo = addressHouseNo;
        this.addressZipCode = addressZipCode;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param id             address's id
     * @param addressStreet  address's street
     * @param addressHouseNo address's house number
     * @param addressZipCode address's zipcode
     */
    public AddressEntity(Long id, String addressStreet, String addressHouseNo, ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
        this.addressHouseNo = addressHouseNo;
        this.addressZipCode = addressZipCode;
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param id             address's id
     * @param addressStreet  address's street
     * @param addressHouseNo address's house number
     * @param user user's entity
     * @param addressZipCode address's zipcode
     */
    public AddressEntity(Long id, String addressStreet, String addressHouseNo, UserEntity user, ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
        this.addressHouseNo = addressHouseNo;
        this.user = user;
        this.addressZipCode = addressZipCode;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public AddressEntity() {
    }

    /**
     * Gets Id
     *
     * @return Adress's Id
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets street
     *
     * @return adress's street
     */
    public String getAddressStreet() {
        return addressStreet;
    }

    /**
     * Sets street
     *
     * @param addressStreet address's street to set
     */
    public void setAddressStreet(String addressStreet) {
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
    }

    /**
     * Gets house number
     *
     * @return address's house number
     */
    public String getAddressHouseNo() {
        return addressHouseNo;
    }

    /**
     * Sets house number
     *
     * @param addressHouseNo address's house number
     */
    public void setAddressHouseNo(String addressHouseNo) {
        this.addressHouseNo = addressHouseNo;
    }

    public UserEntity getUserentity_id() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUserentity_id(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public ZipCodeEntity getAddressZipCode() {
        return addressZipCode;
    }

    public void setAddressZipCode(ZipCodeEntity addressZipCode) {
        this.addressZipCode = addressZipCode;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(addressHouseNo, addressStreet, addressZipCode, id, user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AddressEntity other = (AddressEntity) obj;
        return Objects.equals(addressHouseNo, other.addressHouseNo)
                && Objects.equals(addressStreet, other.addressStreet)
                && Objects.equals(addressZipCode, other.addressZipCode) && id == other.id
                && Objects.equals(user, other.user);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddressEntity [id=" + id + ", addressStreet=" + addressStreet + ", addressHouseNo=" + addressHouseNo
                + ", user=" + user + ", addressZipCode=" + addressZipCode + "]";
    }
}

